# View contents of db after modifying the db without relaunching the app in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

We are developing an app which includes database. Once the database contents are modified/deleted, we are able to see the old contents only. But after relaunching the app the modified/deleted contents will be shown. how to view the contents of the db after modifying the db without relaunching the app.

After update/delete if we click on view button to check the details,its showing the previous values. But once we relaunch the app the database gets modified. We need to see the details immediate after update/delete operation without relaunching the app.

Comment: Your question does not provide enough detail. How about showing some code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this may be an Issue with your Class representing your table. Don't forget to implement "INotifyPropertyChanged"!

A good example of this in use with a database can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: We have used INotifyPropertyChanged method but still we are facing this problem.